# Azure Data Factory Compression Type

Tags: azure, azure-data-factory

I am working on a project trying to zip the files in Azure Blob Storage. I know the Azure Data Factory support compression type option, but I cannot find any reference to how this compression process behaves.

If I want to generate a *.zip file:

Origin Files:

```
ParentFolder
    Image1.jpeg
    Txt1.txt
    ChildFolder
         Image2.jpeg
         Txt.txt
```

Is it going to zip only the ParentFolder? Or it is going to zip every single file recursively?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Compression type seems does not support `.zip`, it just supports `GZIP, Deflate, BZIP2, ZipDeflate`, see this [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/supported-file-formats-and-compression-codecs#compression-support).

I test to copy the files like the sample you mentioned from one storage account to another one, use `GZIP`.

The files after being copied, it will be like as below(choose the `Copy file recursively` option).

```
ParentFolder
    Image1.jpeg.gz
    Txt1.txt.gz
    ChildFolder
         Image2.jpeg.gz
         Txt.txt.gz
```

If not choose the `Copy file recursively` option, it will be like as below.

```
ParentFolder
        Image1.jpeg.gz
        Txt1.txt.gz
```

Comment: Is there anyway to compress like we normally do? (Only the parent folder is being compressed and other files remain same)

Comment: @WilliamShu No, it will not compress the folder, only compresses the file in the folder.

Comment: Thanks Joy but it can't. We are looking for a solution to only compress the ParentFolder. Is there any possibility that other compression options can achieve this goal?

Comment: @WilliamShu Actually what you want to do? Also copy the files from storage blob to another blob?

Comment: The thing is we have files in storage blob, and we want to compress the files.

Comment: @WilliamShu I am afraid you may not do that, the folder in the blob storage is a virtual directory, data factory does not support to compress it.